# Need to create a new repository from the existing one

Tags: git, bitbucket

There was a repository in bitbucket from which I need to copy the contents/code to another(new) repository from where I need to kickstart my project. I [referred](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) and created a mirror repo which contains all the branches as well as the history of the old repo. Unfortunately, I didn't expect this as I just want the code to be migrated.

I want to make sure if

1. I make any push to new mirror repository it won't affect the old repo as they are mirror repositories.
2. Is there any way to remove the branches and history commits which are also migrated from the old repository.
3. What does "git push -mirror" does? (You can refer the link mentioned above)

Besides that what is considered the best way to migrate the code from one repo to another?

Comment: Do you mean you need no link whatsoever between old and new repos ? Just starting a new repo with the present state of the old repo's files ? If so, maybe just get rid of any preexisting .git folder and make a *git init* in the your copied codebase ?

Comment: I did that but I was not able to push the updates

Comment: push where ? If you need a fresh new remote repo, create one on bitbucket and set it as upstream. Did you want to be able to push on the very repo you cloned from....but don't want history from ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Duplicate a repository" *means* duplicate the history and branches.  That's what any clone operation (mirror or otherwise) does, unless you give specific options to limit which part of the history you copy (such as for a shallow clone or a single-branch clone).

To answer your numbered questions:

1) Pushing to the clone will not automatically affect the remote from which it was cloned (or any other remote).  To add content to a remote, you have to explicitly push to it.  This is the same for `--mirror` clones as any other clone.  The only thing different about a `--mirror` clone is the default ref mapping: instead of mapping source branches to remote tracking refs, source branches are mapped to local branches; and all other refs under the `refs/` hierarchy are also mapped "as-is".  (And the default refspec, if you do choose to push or fetch from the source repo, is correspondingly different from a regular clone.)

2) If you just want the current version of the code, one option is: after cloning you can check out the version you want and then either copy the contents to another folder (where you can then `init` a new repo), or `rm -rf .git` to remove the old repo metadata (and then you can `init` a new repo right there).  I wouldn't be surprised if this turns out to be a bad decision, though; once you throw information away, it'snot too easy to get it back if for some reason down the road it turns out to be useful.

Another option is to create a single-branch shallow clone.  This preserves the identity of the commit you copy, in case you should ever want to restore the contextual relationship between your repo and the source repo.

```
git clone --single-branch --depth=1 --mirror <url>
```

If you then want to remove the link to the source repo

```
git remote remove origin
```

(You may get a warning about a ref outside the `refs/remotes` hierarchy not being removed; that's ok.)  Then even doing a `push` from your new repo wouldn't affect the source repo.

3) For `push`, the `--mirror` option means to push every ref under `refs/` to the corresponding ref on the remote.

Lastly,

> Besides that what is considered the best way to migrate the code from one repo to another?

There is no universal answer to that.  It's just going to depend on what information you need from the other repo.  Any of the options outlined above is fine, if it matches what you need.

Comment: Will "git remote remove origin" remove the remote link i.e old repository link from my new repo?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do "git init" will remove all the references with the old repository which was the source to create the mirror repository and after that the new repo is no longer the mirror repository?

Comment: @a123 - No, `git init` will not remove existing remote references.  See the procedures suggested under (2) above.  You either delete the old repo so `git init` can create a new one (in that case, deleting the old repo deletes the link); or you copy the worktree out of the repo and create a new repo around the copy (copy never has the link), or you use `git remote remove origin` to remove the link from the existing repo.  Not sure how to answer about the repo "no longer [being a] mirror".  As I said, the only thing special about a mirror is the refspec, and that's gone if the remote ref is gone